# How to query for results by specifying a condition on a relationship in Core Data?

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

I have two entities `Parent` and `Child` connected by an optional one-to-many relationship. I am trying to write a predicate that will allow me to do the following:

1. Only retrieve `Parent` objects that have `Child` objects in which a specific attribute is set, eg. `name = 'John'`
2. Retrieve `Parent` objects in which only the selected `Child` objects are populated. So in the above case, the `childSet` property would only contain John but not Mary or Peter.

Is there a way to do this in Core Data?

Comment: is childSet a boolean? you want both conditions? I would say that when Parent has a relationship with Child, the child is set. Furthermore I wouldn't use jonh since you can have many children named jonh

Comment: Being a one-to-many relationship it's a set.

Comment: have you tried  NSPredicate(format: "ANY child.name == %@", "jonh")

Comment: is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: That looks like it might solve point 1, but what about point 2?

Comment: I probably don't understand your question. Do you want to fetch both the Parent and the Child?

Comment: I want to limit the Child objects being fetched.